How to make a file gateway in bluetooth to a flutter app?
I need to send from an ESP32 connected with a SD card that store a JSON file to an app developped in flutter.
I want to send this data to bluetooth. However the my file is about 500Ko (for the worstcases) which is a lot for bluetooth. So i'm dividing the file in packets of 128 octets
I know that bluetooth is not the fastest method to send file, if it needs 10 minutes to transfer that's not a problem for me
Principle :
The bluetooth client can send commands to the ESP32 lines : like "downloadfile:/*name_of_the_file.json"

It send back the name of the file, followed by the size of the file and the number of packets
The client send back an Acknowlegement
The transfer starts
-> A header with : Packet number, and size of the packet is send, and then follows the packet
-> The ESP32 waits back for the acknowlegement of the packet (size and packet number)
Once the whole file is recieved Client sends a acknowlegement and then ESP32 confirm that the file send is complete

Problematic :
First I dont know if it's the best solution to send data to a flutter app, I want to stay with bluetooth, maybe BLE could do the job or should fit better to flutter.
Secondly, I'm new to flutter and I dont really know if flutter serial bluetooth is this the simplest solution to program my app.
Most of my test  with the ESP32 is done with "Serial Bluetooth Terminal" App (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal&pli=1)
here are the result for the command : download:/gps_data_1.json :
Download function:
void downloadFile(String filename) {
  if (!fileRead(filename)) {  // Check if the file can be read
    SerialBT.println("ERROR_NO_FILE");  // Send error message if the file doesn't exist
    return;
  }

  getFileDetails(filename);  // Get file details and send them over Bluetooth

  // Wait for a response from the phone: "ACK"
  waitForACK();  // Wait until "ACK" is received

  SerialBT.println("START_TRANSFER");  // Notify the start of the file transfer
  SerialBT.println();  // Empty line for formatting
  Serial.println("START_TRANSFER");  // Print to serial monitor

  // Divide the file into packets and send them one by one
  size_t packetNumber = 0;  // Initialize packet number
  uint8_t buffer[CHUNK_SIZE];  // Buffer for storing chunk of data
  size_t totalPackets = numberPacket(filename);  // Get total number of packets
  while (file.available()) {  // Loop until end of file is reached

    // Read a chunk of data from the file
    size_t bytesRead = file.read(buffer, CHUNK_SIZE);

    // Send packet number and size
    // Packet send check frame format: SEND;PN:*current packet number*/*total number of packets*;PS:*packet size*
    SerialBT.print("SEND;");
    SerialBT.print("PN:");
    SerialBT.print(++packetNumber);
    SerialBT.print("/");
    SerialBT.print(totalPackets);
    SerialBT.print(";");
    SerialBT.print("PS:");
    SerialBT.println(bytesRead);

    // Send the packet
    SerialBT.println();  // Empty line for formatting
    SerialBT.write(buffer, bytesRead);  // Send the data
    SerialBT.println();  // Empty line for formatting

    // Wait for packet acknowledgment from the client
    // Packet receive check frame format: ACK;PNR:*current packet number*/*total number of packets*;PSR:*packet size*
    waitForPacketACK(packetNumber, totalPackets, bytesRead);
  }

  SerialBT.println("TRANSFER_COMPLETE");  // Notify completion of file transfer
  SerialBT.println();  // Empty line for formatting

  Serial.println("TRANSFER_COMPLETE");  // Print to serial monitor
  file.close();  // Close the file
}

Packet dividing function :
size_t numberPacket(String filename) {
  if (!fileRead(filename)) {  // Ajout de la condition pour appeler fileRead()
    return 0;                 // Retourner 0 si le fichier n'est pas trouvé
  }

  // Obtient la taille du fichier
  size_t fileSize = file.size();
  // Estime le nombre de morceaux
  size_t numChunks = fileSize / CHUNK_SIZE;
  if (fileSize % CHUNK_SIZE != 0) {
    numChunks++;  // Ajoute un morceau pour les octets restants
  }
  return numChunks;
}


Hey Gamma, you are mixing two different technologies here. BLE is different to Bluetooth Serial (also called Bluetooth Classic). Using BLE will require you to use an app on your phone while Bluetooth Serial could send the file directly to your phone. Since you already mention your app you could go with BLE, just keep in mind that flutter serial bluetooth is, as the name suggests, not for BLE but for Bluetooth Serial. You need https://github.com/boskokg/flutter_blue_plus
